# Python: How can I iterate over specific data frames in a group of data frames

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I have a folder with multiple txt files with data in different formats, which I am later merging. For the time being I need to get them all formatted the same way.

```
path =r'C:\\Users\\data'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.txt")

dfs = []
for filename in filenames:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(filename, infer_datetime_format=True, sep=None, 
engine='python', header=None))
```

Then I have a specific formatting for a few dataframes in the list:

```
#Format 1

dfs[3][[0,1]]= dfs[3][1].str.split(expand=True)
dfs[4][[0,1]]= dfs[4][1].str.split(expand=True)
dfs[3].columns=['Date','Time','Wind Vel 1','Wind Vel 2','Dir1','Dir2','NaN']
dfs[3] = dfs[3].drop('NaN',1)
dfs[4].columns=['Date','Time','Wind Vel 1','Wind Vel 2','Dir1','Dir2','NaN']
dfs[4] = dfs[4].drop('NaN',1)
```

How do I accomplish this for dfs[3] and dfs[4] in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Easily:

```
for i in (3,4):
    dfs[i][[0,1]]= dfs[i][1].str.split(expand=True)
    dfs[i].columns=['Date','Time','Wind Vel 1','Wind Vel 2','Dir1','Dir2','NaN']
    dfs[i] = dfs[i].drop('NaN',1)
```

Comment: Thank you! was trying similar versions of this but i guess my formatting wasn't quite correct. Is there another method that might be faster than looping for each?